# Best practice for nested packages/class on Android

Tags: android, package

Is there any best practice regarding whether or not nested packages and classes is a good idea?

A) nested packages
i.e. Is it a good idea to have

```
utils
    XXX.java
    xxxx
        XXX.java
        XXX.java
model
view
    activity
    fragment
        dialog (dialogfragment)
            errors
            sth
```

B) nested class
i.e. Is it a good idea to have

```
class Const {
    class static HOST {
        public final static String STAGING = "";
        public final static String PRODUCTION = "";
    }
    class static Foo {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, they are - when they're a good idea; cleanly organized for A, and not like what you wrote for B.

And no, they're not when they're not a good idea which you demonstrated in both A and B in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to take a look at this GitHub https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture made by Google developers. It provides samples to build Android apps using different architectural concepts and tools. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**A)** There is no specific rule about package but a simple rule of thumb is that you should try to minimize package dependency cycling.

> That means one package can depend on an other (or multiple other)
>   package and use their classes but the required package should minimize
>   the dependency to the first package. so the dependeny calls should
>   only go into one direction.

The more common packages are usually `Activities`, `Fragments`, `Services`, `Receivers`, `Adapters`, `Models`, `Utilities` and `Helper` Classes, `Network` and `Database` Packages.

**B)** Usually it's not a good practice to define inner classes especially for libraries that parse classes **Dynamically** like `GSON`. But if you are defining a Class that is **Only** used by a **Specific** Class you can **encapsulate** First class into the Second one for the sake of re-usability.